# What is the difference between Mipmap arrays and Level of Detail?

Tags: opengl, glsl, mipmaps

The textureQueryLod call returns two components:

1. x - Tells in which proportion are mipmap levels used.
2. y - Level of detail.

Are they both same?

Comment: It appears to be derived from this ARB extension: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_query_lod.txt Which has a description that might clear up the issue for you, I'm not sure I can explain it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a problem like this and find it cannot be sufficiently answered by looking at the [basic API documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/textureQueryLod.xml) for a class of GLSL functions, you should consult the [formal GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf).

If you read the specification, specifically ***Section 8.9.1 - Texture Query Functions***, you will come across a very detailed explanation of the "used" mipmap level. In short, this value is the fractional component that would be used to select the nearest mipmap level(s)  during during minification+mipmap filtering.

#### Recall that there are two possible ways to resolve a mipmap sample:

1. Interpolate between the two nearest mipmap LODs (linear mip filter)

   - This is the 3<sup>rd</sup> *linear* in a ***tri***-linear filter
2. Sample the closest mipmap LOD (nearest mip filter)

With that out of the way, you should have the theoretical basis to understand the pseudo-code presented in the specification on pp. 155:

```c
float ComputeAccessedLod(float computedLod)
{
    // Clamp the computed LOD according to the texture LOD clamps.
    if (computedLod < TEXTURE_MIN_LOD) computedLod = TEXTURE_MIN_LOD;
    if (computedLod > TEXTURE_MAX_LOD) computedLod = TEXTURE_MAX_LOD;
    // Clamp the computed LOD to the range of accessible levels.
    if (computedLod < 0.0)
        computedLod = 0.0;
    if (computedLod > (float)
        maxAccessibleLevel) computedLod = (float) maxAccessibleLevel;
    // Return a value according to the min filter.
    if (TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER is LINEAR or NEAREST) {
        return 0.0;
    } else if (TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER is NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST
               or LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST) {
        return ceil(computedLod + 0.5) - 1.0;
    } else {
        return computedLod;
    }
}
```

There are three branches in this pseudo-code:

1. Handles the situation where a sampler does not use mipmapping at all

   - The accessed LOD is always 0.0
2. Handles the situation where a sampler uses a nearest mip filter

   - The accessed LOD is the closest integer
3. Handles the situation where a sampler uses a linear mip filter

   - The accessed LOD is between the two nearest integer LODs
   - **Two** LODs would be sampled in this case, and the single returned sample is interpolated between both based on the fractional part of this value

---

The second component returned by `textureQueryLod (...)` is the unclamped integer LOD.

Comment: Hi Andon, so it is that both x,y point to the mip-map image, only difference being that the x component is processed by the above pseudo-code giving different mip-map level accordingly. The thing that confused me was LOD when read this article [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail] which talks about geometry rather than the texture.

Comment: @abhijitjagdale: Level of detail is just a general term for reduced detail. Mipmap levels are basically an implementation of level of detail, but they serve more purpose than simply performance improvement (they also perform texture anti-aliasing). As for the difference between the X and Y components, X follows the pseudo-code above and gives a value starting at 0.0 (max detail) and works its way to <last lod> (min detail). Y, on the other hand is unclamped it is the actual LOD number (always an integer multiple).

Comment: If Y is an integer multiple, then after passing Y to the function ComputeAccessedLod() to get X will always be an integer.  
Three returns: 
1) returns 0.0   
2) returns ceil(y + 0.5) - 1.0. (eg For y = 5.0, x will be 5.0)  
3) returns y as it is.